# Nested form don't save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, ruby-on-rails-5.1, nested-form-for

I'm new do rails and MVC. I'm trying to save to my database a nested form that I made using simple-form and nested-form-for gems.
When I submit the form only the 'parent' model is created and saved.
Thankyou very much.

'parent model':

```
class Diet < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :coach

    has_many :user_eat_diets
    has_many :user, through: :user_eat_diets
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_eat_diets

    has_many :diet_composes
    has_many :foods, through: :diet_composes
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :diet_composes
end
```

'child' model:

```
class DietCompose < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :diet
    belongs_to :food
end
```

'parent' controller:

```
class DietsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @diet = Diet.new
        @diet.diet_composes.build
    end

    def create
        @diet = Diet.new(diet_params)
        if @diet.save
            flash[:success] = "success"
        end
    end
    def diet_params
      params.require(:diet).permit(:name, :coach_id, :diet_composes_attributes)
    end

end
```

'child' controller:

```
class DietComposesController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @diet_compose = Diet_compose.new
    end

    def create
        @diet_compose = Diet_compose.new(diet_compose_params)
        if @diet_compose.save
            flash[:success] = "success"
        end
    end

    def diet_compose_params
      params.require(:diet_compose).permit(:quantity, :hour, :day, :food_id, :diet_id)
    end
end
```

the form view:

```
<%= simple_form_for @diet, :html => {:class => 'form-basic' }  do |f| %>
            <%= f.input :name %>
            <%= f.input :coach_id %>
            <%= f.nested_fields_for :diet_composes do |ff| %>
                    <%= ff.remove_nested_fields_link %>
                    <%= ff.input :hour %>
                    <%= ff.input :day %>
                    <%= ff.input :food_id %>
                    <%= ff.input :diet_id %>
                <% end %>
            <%= f.add_nested_fields_link :diet_composes %>
            <%= f.button :submit %>
        <% end %>
```

Also, when I do the command

> Diet_compose.all

on rails console I got the error

> LoadError: Unable to autoload constant Diet_compose, expected
>   /home/tanaka/Desktop/E-xercite/app/models/diet_compose.rb to define it
>     from (irb):8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to correct multiple things here. I have added the comments inline.

in `Diet` model (`diet.rb`)

```
class Diet < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessible :diet_composes # make the attributes accessible for mass assignment.
end
```

In controllers:

```
class DietsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @diet = Diet.new
        @diet.diet_composes.build
    end

    def create
        @diet = Diet.new(diet_params)
        if @diet.save
            flash[:success] = "success"
        end
    end
    def diet_params
       # add attributes of nested association to whitelist
      params.require(:diet).permit(:name, :coach_id, :diet_composes_attributes => [:hour, :day, :food_id, :diet_id])
    end

end
```

You don't really need `DietComposesController`'s actions to get your nested attribute of `Diet` working. But still, correcting the errors below which are giving you `LoadError`

```
class DietComposesController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @diet_compose = DietCompose.new # Model name is always CamelCase. DietCompose rather than Diet_compose
    end

    def create
        @diet_compose = DietCompose.new(diet_compose_params) # here as well
        if @diet_compose.save
            flash[:success] = "success"
        end
    end

    def diet_compose_params
      params.require(:diet_compose).permit(:quantity, :hour, :day, :food_id, :diet_id, )
    end
end
```

Your command should be `DietCompose.all`. Even look at the definition of `diet_model.rb`. It declares the name as `DietModel`.

Your view seems fine. I haven't worked with [`nested_form_fields`](https://github.com/ncri/nested_form_fields) gem, so can't be 100% sure. Simple rule of debugging, see the rails server's log and infer :)

Comment: Thanks it worked! But I had to remove the "attr_accessible :diet_composes" looks like it don't exist for rails 4.0+. One more thinh how can I auto set the diet_id of the diet_composes to be set equal to the diet_id that I just created with the form?